# How to trigger another modal from PartialView

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I'm trying to trigger another modal while im inside of the current modal.
My current modal is coming from `PartialView` and its works well, let me show to you

[image]

my point is triggering to Shopping Cart when the user clicks to `View Cart` button which is insides of the first modal. So the first step is closing that current modal and trigger another one. Let me show to you my Shopping Cart ;

[image]

so i hope u guys understand what i was trying to meant it. My codes are bellowed;

The Html :

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <a href="#" class="tt-cart-total" id="currentCountOfCartForModal">
        There are 1 items in your cart
        <div class="tt-total">
            TOTAL: <span class="tt-price">$324</span>
        </div>
    </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-border btn-close-popup">CONTINUE SHOPPING</a>
        <a data-target="/Base/CartPartialView/" class="sepet btn btn-border">VIEW CART</a> //That's the link which is gonna trigger to Shopping Cart
        <a href="@Url.Action("CardIndex","Payment")" class="btn">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</a>
</div>
```

The Script :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".modal-body").on("click", ".sepet", function () {
            document.getElementById("modalClose").click();
            var url = $(this).data("target");
            console.log(url);
            $.post(url, function (data) { })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $("#modelView .tt-cart-content").html(data);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    $("#modelView .tt-cart-content").text("Error!!");
                })
        });
    })
</script>
```

This is works on me like that :
[Gif](https://gifyu.com/image/1PbL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the modal to fully close, and then call `show` on your shopping cart modal, or simply just trigger a click event on your link.

Example:

```js
$('#YOUR_MODAL_SELECTOR_WHICH_YOU_CLOSE').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  //...
  $('a.sepet').click();
  //...
}
```